# How to save a date into rails using the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, console

I have a table that has a date field in it.  How would I save the date using the console?  I tried 
`event = Event.create(name:"Concert", date:08/20/2016, location:'Portland', state:'OR')`
However, I am getting an Invalid octal digit error.

Comment: Your date is not a string, so it's parsed as number. Numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as Octal and 8 is not a valid digit there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll want to pass in an actual [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) object, which you can get from a string with the `Date.parse` method:

```
event = Event.create(name: "Concert", date: Date.parse('2016-08-20'), location: 'Portland', state: 'OR')
```

Note that I've rewritten your date to be in a different format. The `MM/DD/YYYY` format is **not** portable across locales, so I'd strongly suggest you use `YYYY-MM-DD` (the ISO 8601 format).

Answer (score 3):

Using a string in the correct format will do the trick. For example:

```
>> foo = Foo.create date: "20/8/2016"
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "foos" ("date") VALUES (?)  [["date", Sat, 20 Aug 2016]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
#<Foo id: 1, date: "2016-08-20">
>> foo.date
Sat, 20 Aug 2016
```

ActiveSupport provides core extensions on the String class for conversions from strings to date, time, and datetime. This is probably ok, and more convenient, to take advantage of while testing around in Rails console.

Taking advantage of this extension in the application itself (instead of explicitly parsing with `Date.parse`) is totally up to you and your team.

From the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/149c144409cc9cbc4e960dbd70c9c77d86b06d8d/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/conversions.rb):

```
"1-1-2012".to_date   # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012
"01/01/2012".to_date # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012
"2012-12-13".to_date # => Thu, 13 Dec 2012
"12/13/2012".to_date # => ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Just to be thorough, examples for `String#to_time`

```
"13-12-2012".to_time               # => 2012-12-13 00:00:00 +0100
"06:12".to_time                    # => 2012-12-13 06:12:00 +0100
"2012-12-13 06:12".to_time         # => 2012-12-13 06:12:00 +0100
"2012-12-13T06:12".to_time         # => 2012-12-13 06:12:00 +0100
"2012-12-13T06:12".to_time(:utc)   # => 2012-12-13 06:12:00 UTC
"12/13/2012".to_time               # => ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

And `String#to_datetime`:

```
"1-1-2012".to_datetime            # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +0000
"01/01/2012 23:59:59".to_datetime # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 23:59:59 +0000
"2012-12-13 12:50".to_datetime    # => Thu, 13 Dec 2012 12:50:00 +0000
"12/13/2012".to_datetime          # => ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, for example:

```
date = Date.parse('3rd Feb 2001')  ####=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
```

Reference: [Date class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)